# How to bind Kendo.Combobox to its datasource on "Edit" event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datasource, kendo-combobox

I need to populate `Kendo.Combobox` on its container's `Edit` event:

I have a Grid that defines `EditTemplate` for a Kendo.Combobox:

```
co.Bound(c => c.PropertyName).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor");
```

The combobox is defined as follows in `EditTemplate`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("ReportProperty")
    .DataTextField("PropertyName")
    .DataValueField("ReportPropertyID")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "ReportPropertyCB" })
)
```

The Grid has an event that fires `Edit` javascript function:

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("Databound").Edit("Edit"))
```

I need to populate combobox on that `Edit` event:

```
function Edit(e) {

    $.ajax({

        //url: "/TicketReportProperty/PopulateReportProperty",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {'reportId' : @Html.Raw(Model.ReportID)},
        success: function (data)
        {
            $("idCB").html = '';
            if (data != '')
            {
               console.log(data);  
            if (data != '') {
                $(data.Data).each(function () {
                    console.log(this.PropertyName + " " + this.ReportGroup);
                    $("#ReportPropertyCB").append($("<option></option>").html(this.PropertyName));
                });                   
            }
            }
        }   
  });  
}
```

The controller's method:

```
public JsonResult PopulateReportProperty([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id)
{
    myModel model = new myModel();
    var dataList = model.GetDataList(id);
    return Json(rdata.ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When printing out the returned collection on console, I have something like that:
[image]

How can I accomplish that?

And when html is generated, it looks like that:

[image]

It generated , but it does not show them inside of a combobox.